# SimpleCookie generic type

Tags: python, mypy, python-3.8

`SimpleCookie` is apparently a generic type and thus the following code (test.py) gives an error when checked with `mypy`:

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

cookie = SimpleCookie()
```

> test.py:3: error: Need type annotation for 'cookie'

Now if I change test.py line 3 to:

```
cookie: SimpleCookie = SimpleCookie()
```

I get the following error:

> test.py:3: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "SimpleCookie"

`SimpleCookie` inherits from `dict`, has `str` keys and `Morsel` values, so I'd assume that the correct generic type annotation is something like this:

```
from http.cookies import Morsel, SimpleCookie

cookie: SimpleCookie[str, Morsel] = SimpleCookie()
```

But now the error is:

> test.py:3: error: "SimpleCookie" expects 1 type argument, but 2 given

Changing line 3 to

```
cookie: SimpleCookie[str] = SimpleCookie()
```

suddenly makes `mypy` happy, but leaves me very confused why this is the correct solution, so I have two questions:

1. Why is `SimpleCookie` a generic type with one argument?
2. What's the best way to handle this in my code? Should I annotate `SimpleCookie` variables with `SimpleCookie[str]` (which seems like a lie to me) or should I just annotate them with `Any` and hope this will be cleaned up in future Python versions?

`mypy` version 0.750 and Python 3.8.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Explanation

`str` in `SimpleCookie[str]` actually refers to the type `_T` of `coded_value` in `Morsel`.

`mypy` uses https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/http/cookies.pyi:

```py
class Morsel(Dict[str, Any], Generic[_T]):
    value: str
    coded_value: _T
    key: str
    def set(self, key: str, val: str, coded_val: _T) -> None: ...
    # ...

class BaseCookie(Dict[str, Morsel[_T]], Generic[_T]):
    # ...
    def value_decode(self, val: str) -> _T: ...
    def value_encode(self, val: _T) -> str: ...
    # ...
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: Union[str, Morsel[_T]]) -> None: ...

class SimpleCookie(BaseCookie[_T], Generic[_T]): ...
```

## Correct typing

`_T` should be `Any`, i.e. `SimpleCookie[Any]`, as explained in [python/typeshed#3060](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/3060):

> Morsel does cast any value to string ... max-age can take an integer (unix time) and http-only a boolean.

Actually, I could not reproduce the error you get with this:

```py
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

cookie: SimpleCookie = SimpleCookie()
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Weird that you can't reproduce, I double checked now and I get the same error with mypy==0.750 and Python 3.8.0 (Conda distribution).

Comment: There is one thing I don't get about the type signature of `SimpleCookie`: why does it intherit from `Generic[_T]` again? Wouldn't it be generic by virtue of inheriting from `BaseCookie`?

Comment: Yes, it would. Seems like just being explicit from the start: [python/typeshed@e97638d#diff-9c3523d2a7593f7bb448bb4c0d504f5a](https://github.com/python/typeshed/commit/e97638d4bd03b1e5fc5a09904a17018f389ec673#diff-9c3523d2a7593f7bb448bb4c0d504f5a)